# Strawberry Perl negative child pid when forked

Tags: windows, perl, fork, strawberry-perl

So I understand that Windows does not support the Unix fork-exec model and instead spawns processes. However, Strawberry Perl's fork emulation produces children with negative PIDs. These PIDs appear to be consistent, but I don't understand why they are negative or, really, how Perl is emulating Unix fork.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $cpid = fork();

if ($cpid == 0) {
    printf "%s\n", "I'm the child, pid is $$";
} else {
    printf "%s\n", "I'm the parent, pid is $$, cpid is $cpid";
}
```

This produces something similar to:

```
I'm the parent, pid is 3428, cpid is -2600
I'm the child, pid is -2600
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the details are in [perlfork](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfork.html), but to answer your specific questions, Pseudo-processes for Perl on Windows are actually implemented as threads.  You should interpret a positive PID to be the actual PID of the original thread and negative PIDs are actually thread IDs (negated, of course).

Comment: "You should interpret a positive PID to be the actual PID of the original thread and negative PIDs are actually thread IDs" Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: I read perlfork and couldn't tell where the negative numbers are coming from, only that mysterious things happen with `wait` if you get a pseudo-pid of -1

Answer (score 3):

If positive PIDs were used for the fake processes created by `fork` (which are actually threads), they could conflict with PIDs of actual processes.